# Transfer data from table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with columns `(date_to, bil_id, member_pay, yot)`

I need to transfer the data from columns `(bil_id,  member_pay,  yot)`  to another table with columns `(bil_id, member_pay, yot, bil_id, date_of_)` and then delete the data from the first table.

How can I do it?

Comment: Is this homework? How do the fields in table1 map to those in table2? Are all the records supposed to be moved?

Comment: Are you sure there are two columns in `table2` that is named `bil_id`?

Comment: I meant something like that insert into t2(bil_id, member_pay, yot )date_of_
select bil_id , member_pay, yot from t1 But it does not work

Comment: You need to show what you've tried and what "does not work" means. We're helpful but we're not psychic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into T2(bil_id, member_pay, yot, date_of_to)
select bil_id, member_pay, yot, getdate()
from T1;

delete from T1;
```

Comment: this I know but I need also insert the date_of_ to the table t2

Comment: @jog do you want today's date?

Comment: I added the date_of_to field an fills it with getdate(). That is the current date and time. What do you want in that field?

Comment: the field it is nvarchar how i can input som string